# Using WildFly23 with eclipse 2020-06

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

How can I configure a WildFly 23 on a Eclipse 2020-06? I installed the JbossTools from Eclipse Marketplace (4.16.0.Final) but in the server list only appears until Wildfly 20.

I want to work with Eclipse 2020-06 beacuse is the last version that runs in Java 8 according the eclipse documentation (1) and Wildfly 23 is also compatible with Java 8 (2).

(1) https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

(2) https://docs.wildfly.org/23/Getting_Started_Guide.html

Thanks!

Comment: The version of Java you use to run Eclipse can be different from the version of Java you use to run applications - so use the latest Eclipse.

Comment: Don't use an Eclipse older than the Wildfly release you're trying to work on. Get the latest one.